# JSONException using Netflix Eureka

Tags: java, tomcat7, spring-boot, json, netflix-eureka

I'm pretty new to Netflix Eureka and SpringBoot. I built a very simple Eureka server and client in order to get to see how they get alond discovery-wise. The Eureka server loads itself normally as I get to see the UI when going to localhost:8761/

I am running those two instances with Eclipse's Tomcat.

The Eureka client I built is free of code, as it only runs the SpringBoot app, with the proper annotations. Same stuff about the Eureka server.

When I run the client, after running the server, I get the following stacks. I ran over the web to get some explanations but I didn't find any. Do you know what is causing these JSONObject exceptions ?

Server side stack : http://pastebin.ca/2968955

Client side stack : http://pastebin.ca/2968957

Here's the code that I have :

EurekaServer.java :

```html
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServer {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
         SpringApplication.run(EurekaServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

EurekaServer's application.yml :

```html
spring:
  application:
    name: EurekaServer

server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    festRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```

EurekaClientApp.java :

```html
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EnableEurekaClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@RestController
public class EurekaClientApp {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(EurekaClientApp.class, args);
 }
}
```

EurekaClient's Application.yml :

```html
spring:
  application:
    name: EurekaClient
    
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: false
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 10
    metadataMap:
      instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

server:
  port: 8188
```

eureka-client.properties :

```html
eureka.port=8188
eureka.vipAddress=productservice.mydomain.net
eureka.preferSameZone=true
eureka.shouldUseDns=false
eureka.availabilityZones=default
eureka.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after few hours of failed attemps at making it work by modifying the code, I looked at the `pom.xml` file and I removed the dependencies that were attached to this part of the application. And I put them back on, one by one, verifying the modifications it would do, and I found out that I had the wrong dependency regarding `eureka`, as I replaced the one I had e.g. `com.netflix.eureka` by the one provided by springboot, e.g. `spring-cloud-starter-eureka`.